# Sqoop export to SQL Server fails if password is provided in password file

Tags: sql-server, sqoop

I am trying to export data from HDFS to SQL Server, it works fine if I provide the password as an argument. However, if I provide password file then it fails.

Password file has an only single line, password only. No New line or special character at the end of the line.

The same thing works for Netezza, it fails only for SQL Server

- Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.5.3.0-37
- Driver Jar: sqljdbc4-2.0.jar

Command:

```
sqoop export --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://abc.com:58850;databaseName=IKB_PROD;schema=dbo;" --table "SQOOP_TEST_SMALL" --export-dir /tmp/SQOOP_TEST_SMALL_20180101_010101 --username HADOOP_USR --password-file /user/gaurang.shah/sqlserver_password.pass --verbose
```

Error:

> Warning: /usr/hdp/2.5.3.0-37/accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
>   Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
>   18/03/19 15:18:55 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.5.3.0-37
>   18/03/19 15:18:55 DEBUG tool.BaseSqoopTool: Enabled debug logging.
>   18/03/19 15:18:55 DEBUG password.FilePasswordLoader: Fetching password from specified path: /user/gaurang.shah/sqlserver_password.pass
>   18/03/19 15:18:56 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: org.apache.sqoop.manager.oracle.OraOopManagerFactory
>   18/03/19 15:18:56 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory
>   18/03/19 15:18:56 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Trying ManagerFactory: org.apache.sqoop.manager.oracle.OraOopManagerFactory
>   18/03/19 15:18:56 DEBUG oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop can be called by Sqoop!
>   18/03/19 15:18:56 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Trying ManagerFactory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory
>   18/03/19 15:18:56 DEBUG manager.DefaultManagerFactory: Trying with scheme: jdbc:sqlserver:
>   18/03/19 15:18:56 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
>   18/03/19 15:18:56 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Instantiated ConnManager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager@6f0628de
>   18/03/19 15:18:56 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
>       18/03/19 15:18:56 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Execute getColumnInfoRawQuery : SELECT t.* FROM [SQOOP_TEST_SMALL] AS t WHERE 1=0
>       18/03/19 15:18:56 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: No connection paramenters specified. Using regular API for making connection.
>       18/03/19 15:18:56 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'HADOOP_USR'.
>       com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'HADOOP_USR'.
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:196)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:246)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:83)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2532)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:1929)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1917)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4026)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1416)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1061)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:833)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:716)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:904)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:763)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:786)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:289)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:260)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:246)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:328)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1853)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1653)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:64)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:100)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:225)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:243)
>       18/03/19 15:18:56 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Encountered IOException running export job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter

Comment: The password file is in HDFS right?